# Quick Levelling System on Roblox RPG games

Tags: lua, roblox, levels

Hello fellow people this is nearly my first time scripting and I'm looking on fixing a premade levelling system. It's a pretty quick leveling system and the problem is if the player has far over the experience required for levelling up 1 time, how can I make that happen instantly like this example:

**I have 10 million experience and I just need 10k to level up. How can I make that happen instantly and reach level 100k?**

Since I don't want players to have experience issues in my game so please help.

```
local LevelUp = function(plr, Level, XP)
    if XP.Value >= Level.Value * 25 then
        -- Leveling
        XP.Value = XP.Value - Level.Value * 25 
        Level.Value = Level.Value + 1
        -- Health
        if (not plr.Character) then return end
        local hum = plr.Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
        hum.MaxHealth = hum.MaxHealth + 10
    end
end


game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    
    plr.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(chr)
        local hum = chr:WaitForChild("Humanoid",10)
        local leaderstats = plr:WaitForChild("leaderstats")
        local Level = leaderstats:WaitForChild("Level")
        repeat wait() until plr:FindFirstChild("DataLoaded")~=nil
        hum.MaxHealth = Level.Value * 10 + 100
        hum.Health = hum.MaxHealth
    end)
    
    local leaderstats = plr:WaitForChild("leaderstats")
    local Level = leaderstats:WaitForChild("Level")
    local XP = leaderstats:WaitForChild("XP")
    
    Level.Changed:Connect(function() wait() LevelUp(plr, Level, XP) end)
    XP.Changed:Connect(function() wait() LevelUp(plr, Level, XP) end)
end)
```

This is what the script looks like. What should I add to be able to "skip" the overflow experience, causing players to level slowly?

[This is what the levels looks like right now. I'm staying still for the past hour now (Td = 1+e42)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3QiB.png)

Comment: Do I understand it right that you want to round up the number?

Answer (score 0):

A while-loop would be a simple tool to use here.

When a player gets a chunk of experience, you call the `LevelUp` function. Then, while the player has enough experience, increase the player level. The while-loop will continue to execute this loop until they no longer have enough experience to continue leveling.

```
local function LevelUp(plr, Level, XP)
    -- find the player's humanoid
    local hum = nil
    if (plr.Character) then
        hum = plr.Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
    end

    local currentLevel = Level.Value
    local currentExp = XP.Value
    local targetExp = Level.Value * 25
    while (curentExp >= targetExp) do
        -- Leveling
        currentExp -= targetExp
        currentLevel += 1

        -- Recalculate how much experience we need for the next level
        targetExp = currentLevel * 25

        -- Increase the Player's health
        if (hum) then
            hum.MaxHealth = hum.MaxHealth + 10
        end
    end

    -- update the NumberValues at the end so we don't kick off endless while loops
   if (currentLevel ~= Level.Value) then
       Level.Value = currentLevel
   end
   if (currentExp ~= XP.Value) then
       XP.Value = currentExp
   end
end
```